# Has Stephen Bannon ever used the word "nigger" publicly?

Tags: united-states, politics, racism

According to this [video](https://youtu.be/Rhv8LlMvovU), Charles Kaiser said in reference to Trump’s choice of White House senior adviser, Stephen Bannon,

> “then don’t choose … a man who uses the word **nigger** …”

Has Stephen Bannon ever used the word "nigger" publicly?

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Comment: I understand that you aren't from the USA (neither am I!) but you should be aware that this word is considered extremely offensive there, and this question may be seen as provocative. To date, [no topics have been declared taboo here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/892/23) - although we try to be sensitive about suicide.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Esquire](http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/news/a50924/cnn-guest-n-word-quoting-steve-bannon/) on the same day reported:

> The guest, Charles Kaiser, has apologized for "misattributing" the quote to Steve Bannon. Kaiser told Washington Post media reporter Erik Wemple Tuesday afternoon that he meant to say that Trump Attorney General nominee Jeff Sessions had used the N-word, not Bannon.